# Need Page Scroll data Loader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I am working on an app which work as a social media. I am using technology Angular 4 and for Backend RubyonRails.

I need a data loader. In which first time on page load 15 post show on the page. Once User scroll down 5 more previous post come at bottom and top 5 post hide.

```
this.zone.run(() =>{
  this.postservice.doAllPost(this.globalService.user_token).subscribe((response: any) => {
    this.allPosts = response.posts;
    for (let post of this.allPosts){
      this.formPostObject = this.fb.group({
        post_text : new FormControl(post.post_text, Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        id : new FormControl(post.id),
      });

      this.formPostCollection.push(this.formPostObject);
    }
    this.loading = false;
  });
});
```

This is my posts data code.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: check this [package](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll)

Comment: I already check this link. This will not work. Because i need the page loader which show 5 previous post and hide 5 top post.

Comment: you can manually hide top 5 posts on scroll-down event, there is not going to be package which fulfill all your requirements,  you need to make some tweaks